# How access subdirectory file in wowza that use secure token

Tags: security, wowza

I can streami '~/test/test.mp4' file while set secure token is 'Do NOT use SecureToken'.

But I can't stream '~/test/test.mp4' file while secure token is 'Protect all protocols using hash (SecureToken version 2)'.

Also, I can stream '~/test.mp4' file while secure token is 'Protect all protocols using hash (SecureToken version 2)'.

Example:

```
Do NOT use SecureToken
success
rtmp://example.com:1935/vod/_definst_/mp4:test/test.mp4
success
rtmp://example.com:1935/vod/mp4:test.mp4

Protect all protocols using hash (SecureToken version 2)
fail
rtmp://jungslab.com:1935/vod/_definst_/mp4:test/test.mp4?wowzatokenendtime=1461729940&wowzatokenstarttime=1461719140&wowzatokenhash=nB0hdUG-U60WAQ-wV5lIRD0e3tbCCXk3tBWrLXxb90M=
success
rtmp://example.com:1935/vod/mp4:test.mp4?wowzatokenendtime=1461729868&wowzatokenstarttime=1461719068&wowzatokenhash=KpioKfCCQQoeVT4lwLUnwC2xhDG-HOS2kRtAx5PEHhY=
```

How access a subdirectory file in wowza that uses secure token.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Wowza here seems to be with parsing query string. If you can't change the content directory in you vod/Application.xml (or you don't want to do so) to the test subdirectory (or any other mount) you may try moving the query string right after the instance specification app/(definst?qs=/file) or use [plugin](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?348-How-to-fix-incorrect-stream-path-problems-with-some-Flash-players-%28ModuleFixStreamPath%29) to obey the directory structure completely.

Address to try for your file could be:

```
rtmp://jungslab.com:1935/vod/_definst_?wowzatokenendtime=1461729940&wowzatokenstarttime=1461719140&wowzatokenhash=nB0hdUG-U60WAQ-wV5lIRD0e3tbCCXk3tBWrLXxb90M=/mp4:test/test.mp4
```

(adjust your token info for valid)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version/build that you have, there was a previous bug found (on 4.3.0.01 and earlier) where subdirectories were not parsed correctly with Secure Token enabled. You should try:

```
rtmp://jungslab.com:1935/vod/mp4:_definst_/test/test.mp4?wowzatokenendtime=1461729940&wowzatokenstarttime=1461719140&wowzatokenhash=nB0hdUG-U60WAQ-wV5lIRD0e3tbCCXk3tBWrLXxb90M=
```

You will need to re-generate your hash since your stream path has changed.

Alternatively, you can install the latest build from Wowza, since the fix should be in the latest available patch.

As a troubleshooting tool, you can add the Boolean properties securityDebugLogRejections and securityDebugLogDetails to your conf/appName/Application.xml file to output additional debug information to your logs/wowzastreamingengine_access.log file. In particular, you can see what string the server is using to generate the hash, and why the received hash was rejected.